# Keys of a relation

Tags: database-design, primary-key, relational-theory

I got relation:

> R = { (ABCDEF) , (A B F -> C, B C -> F, F -> A, F -> B, D E -> E, E -> D)}

keys of this relation are:

> {BCE}, {EF}

But I don't get it... why? Why not only {EF}.. it got less attributes than {BCE}..

Another example, relation:

> R2 = {(ABCDEF), (A -> B C , B -> D , E -> F)}

and the key is:

> {AE}

why only one? Why not:

> {AE}, {ABE}

ABE also determines all other attributes, why is it not a key?

Comment: In the 2nd question, `ABCDEF` also determines all attributes. Why not that too?

Comment: Yea, I know it determines all atributes. And I ask myself the same question. Why not? Thats what i am asking. Maybe its the dumbest question I have ever asked.. but there it is.

Comment: Revisit your notes about the definition of a key. See also the [Wikipedia page on Superkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey) where what you call a key (if I understand you correctly) is referred to as a "candidate key" or "minimal superkey". The key word (sorry for the pun) is **minimal.**

Comment: I understand why EF is a key (first example) - its obvious. There are no keys among 1-attribute expressions, and EF is a key among 2-attribute expressions. But why BCE is also a key? How can it be minimal if it has 3 attributes, and EF got 2... 2 < 3. Therefore BCE is not minimal.

Comment: Minimal does not mean smallest in size (number of attributes). But smallest when compared as sets. Means it has no subset which is also a superkey. No subset of `EF` and no subset of `BCE` is a superkey, so these two are the minimal superkeys.

Answer (score 0):

Any relation has multiple keys present in it. The primary key is the minimal key amongst these various candidate keys which we can choose from. Candidate keys are a minimal cover of attributes which determines a tuple. We can have many many candidate keys.

The reason A,B,C,D,E,F,G is a key is since it is not a minimal cover of attributes that determine the entire tuple. In the second example, B is not part of the minimal cover since removing it from the candidate key still makes the remaining attributes a candidate key!

Comment: Your first sentence does not sound right - how about relations with only one attribute?

Comment: And theory does not distinguish between primary key and alternate (candidate) keys. This (that we distinguish between the 1 PRIMARY KEY and multiple UNIQUE ones), making the primary somehow more important, is just an implementation choice (made by SQL).